# Find $n$ such that $n$ does not divide any integer in the set

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> You are given a set of integers $\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, \ldots\}$. Find the minimum $n$ that does not divide any number of the set.

This is a programming problem, but I am looking for a mathematical solution.

Comment: $a * b * c * d * e *.. + 1$ clearly doesn't divide any number of the set. But can we find a smaller number? Or is this the minimum? This should help you.

Comment: assume the set is {2, 3, 7, 8}. but the ans is 5. so your algorithm is incorrect

Comment: An upper bound for the desired number is the smallest prime greater than the largest number of the set. It should be easy to find the minimum with that.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah I've said that $a * b * c *... + 1$ is the upper limit, not the answer.

Comment: @scummy, i've edited the question

Comment: Note that if $r$ does not divide any number in the set, then each of the divisors of $r$ has this property. So, you can assume that you're looking for a prime number $p$ that doesn't divide any of the numbers.

To find such a $p$, factorize each of the numbers in the set and find the minimal prime not in the set.

Comment: worth remarking that it is not enough to find the least prime which doesn't appear on the list.  Take the list of the first billion primes, say.  Then the least prime not mentioned is very large indeed, but the answer to the problem is just $4$.

Comment: @lulu is right, I stumbled on the smaller set $A = \{ 2,3\}$ when looking for a proof.

Comment: Also worth remarking:  it is not true that the answer has to be a prime or prime power.  If the list is, say, $\{2,3,4,5\}$ then the answer is $6$.  This, sadly, is also a counterexample to the notion that the answer is the least integer not to divide the LCM of the numbers in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Let the set be $A = \{ n_1, \ldots, n_N \}$, where the elements $n_i$ are sorted in ascending order. Let $P(n)$ be true, if and only if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ does not divide any element of $A$. So $n>1$. The task is to find a minimal $n$ with that property $P$ true for $A$.

Each number $n_i$ uniquely factorizes into 
$$
n_i = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots
$$
where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime number and the exponent is a non-negative integer.

Its divisors aside from $1$ are products of its prime factors
(those prime numbers with non-zero exponents) with exponents such that these do not exceed the $e_i$.

A candidate for a solution $n$ must not be a divisor for any $n_i$. So it can not be any of the occuring prime factors.

The smallest prime number $p$ not occurring is not a divisor to any $n_i$.

As Ruben pointed out, another upper bound is $n_N+1$. The set $\{ 2,4\}$ prefers $p=3<4+1=5$, the set $\{ 2,3\}$ prefers $n_2+1=4<5$.

Up to this point we can limit the solution to
$$
B = \{ 2, \ldots, \min(p, n_N+1) \}
$$

If there is a number $n$ smaller than $p$, which would do the job, it itself must be a product of prime numbers, each of these smaller than $p$.

So how can we combine those prime factors such to keep $P$ true?

One could try a prime factor with exponent one larger than it showed up in the $n_i$. For $\{ 2,3,6 \}$ it would give $2^{1+1}=4$ and $3^{1+1}=9$ where $4$ beats $p=5$ and $6+1=7$ as upper bounds.

A practical problem is to decide when to invest the effort determining the prime factors.

Comment: I've edited the questoin a bit. will this still work?

Comment: I've edited the answer a bit too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any nice solution.  You only need to check primes and prime powers as possible answers, but that is not much of a savings.  If $6$ were to not be a divisor of some number, either $2$ or $3$ is already not a divisor.

Answer (score 1):

An trivial algorithm would be to just test for each natural number $k \geq 2$ if it divides any of the numbers in the list. This algorithm runs in ($O(m^2)$, where $m$ is the biggest number from the set), assuming that checking for divisibility takes constant time (which is not true for big enough integers). Note that $m + 1$ is always a solution, since a divisor $d$ of $n$ always satisfies $d \leq n$. $m + 1$ is the solution when the set is $\{ 2, 3, 4, ..., m - 1, m \}$. It is not true that the solution needs to be a prime (unless you require $\gcd(s, n) = 1$ for the solution $s$ and all $n$ in the set).

```
function answer(set S)
    for each 1 < k < m + 2
        isdivisor = false
        for each n in set S
            if k divides n
                isdivisor = true
                break (exit from inner for loop)
        if not(isdivisor) return k
```

In practice, it looks like the running time will depend mainly on the answer, and will be approximately linear in it.

More abstract, if we write the set as $\{ n_1, ..., n_m \}$ and write $n_j = \prod^\infty_{k = 1} p_{k}^{q_{j,k}} $ where $p_k$ is the kth prime number, the solution we seek is a sequence $l_1, l_2, ...$ with $\forall j \in [1, ..., m]$ $\exists t$ $l_t > q_{j, k}$ which minimizes $ s = \prod^\infty_{k = 1} p_k^{l_k} $.

I'm still thinking about a more efficient algorithm based on this description and Eratosthenes' sieve, but I don't think there is a particularly nice one. It is not hard to give bounds on the solution. We have $2 \leq s \leq m + 1$ and $s \leq p_k^w$, where $w = 1 + \max_{j \in \mathbb{N}} q_{j, k}$ for each prime $p_k$.